# JavaFX Fill empty space when component is not visible?

Tags: javafx, visibility

i use Linux Suse 12.3, JDK 1.7.0-45, JavaFX 2.2.

my Question is: why the following Code not working and how to implement a toggleShow/hide functionality?

here is my Test Code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        launch(args); 
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();


        BorderPane inner = new BorderPane();

        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(inner, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(inner, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(inner, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(inner, 0.0);

        final HTMLEditor center = new HTMLEditor();

        final ToolBar top = new ToolBar();
        final Button button = new Button("hide");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                top.setVisible(false);
                //center.setPrefSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
            }
        });     

        center.setManaged(false);
        top.getItems().add(button);
        //top.managedProperty().bind(top.visibleProperty());
        top.setManaged(false);

        inner.setTop(top);
        inner.setCenter(center);

        root.getChildren().add(inner);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

what i want is the same effect as the Solution of Sergey to this Question but without changing width/height!:

[How to solve the overlapping of the controls each other belonging to two different panes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837529/how-to-solve-the-overlapping-of-the-controls-each-other-belonging-to-two-differe?rq=1)

as i said its just a Test Code. i tried using another Layouts as BorderPane but still not working. i don't want to recalculate the size's manually ...etc. Removing the node and adding it again is not an option for me.

whats wrong in my Code? any idea is welcomed!
thanks

Comment: What is not working?  What would working mean?  What is it supposed to do and how exactly does that differ from what it is doing?

Comment: @jewelsea: the title of my post is: JavaFX Fill empty space when component is not visible? in other words, if the top Component is not visible, center component have to take the full size.

Comment: @jewelsea: why down voting if you didn't read the title?

Comment: I read the title, read the text and ran the code and couldn't work out what the question was.  Just me, at the time, I couldn't interpret it, perhaps others will be able to understand and assist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filling the empty space with the usage of `BorderPane` seems to be not an option, due to the prompt in its javadoc:

> BorderPane lays out each child set in the five positions regardless of
>   the child's visible property value; unmanaged children are ignored.

Additionally, using `AnchorPane` just for resizable content as:

```
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(inner, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(inner, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(inner, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(inner, 0.0);
```

seems to be an overusing. Just using the `VBox` will be more suitable for your layout case.

Rewritten test code:

```
@Override
public void start(final Stage stage) {
    final HTMLEditor center = new HTMLEditor();
    final ToolBar top = new ToolBar();

    final Button button = new Button("hide");
    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            top.setVisible(false);
            top.setManaged(false);
        }
    });
    top.getItems().add(button);

    VBox inner = new VBox();
    inner.getChildren().addAll(top, center);
    Scene scene = new Scene(inner, 600, 400);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Now the question is;
How are you going to implement the "show" part of your "show/hide" toggle bar? Since there is no clue about it in your question.

Comment: thanks for your Answer/tips. thats exactly what im looking for. as i said, its just a test to see if its possiple to do such "effect". i have an Application written in Swings and before i rewrite it in Fx i want to test if all features are available or maybe better...etc.

Comment: top.setVisible(false);
 top.setManaged(false);

do works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `top.setManaged(false);` line and then put the toolbar into a `Group` object like this:

```java
Group g = new Group();
Region spacer = new Region();
spacer.setPrefWidth(10000);
spacer.setMinWidth(100);    
top.getItems().add(spacer);
g.getChildren().add(top); //Toolbar here...
inner.setTop(g); //set Group into Borderpane instead of the toolbar
```

After clicking the button the free space is consumed entirely by the HTML-Editor.